# ng2-dragula modelDrop event causing array to be undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, dragula, ng2-dragula

Can't seem to work out why this isn't working.

So as you can see in this GIF I am dragging a div from one container to another, ondrop` the object disappears and the array becomes undefined.
[image]

Here is the code I have:

**Main View.html**

```
<div *ngIf="tvRequests">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="landing-box">
            <md-card-title>Title</md-card-title>
            <div [dragula]='"requests-bag"' [dragulaModel]="tvRequests.new">
                <br />
                <br />
                <request-card *ngFor="let item of tvRequests.new" [request]="item"></request-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="landing-box">

            <div [dragula]='"requests-bag"' [dragulaModel]="tvRequests.approved">
                <br />
                <br />
                <request-card *ngFor="let item of tvRequests.approved" [request]="item"></request-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="landing-box">
            <md-card-title>Title</md-card-title>
            <div style="border: dashed">
                <div [dragula]='"requests-bag"' [dragulaModel]="tvRequests.available">
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <request-card *ngFor="let item of tvRequests.available" [request]="item"></request-card>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Main View.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DragulaService } from 'ng2-dragula/ng2-dragula';
import { RequestService } from '../services/request.service';
import { ITvRequestModel, IMovieRequestModel, IRequestGrid } from '../interfaces/IRequestModel';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: './request-grid.component.html'
})
export class RequestGridComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private dragulaService: DragulaService, private requestService: RequestService) {
        this.dragulaService.dropModel.subscribe((value: any) => {
            console.log(value);
            console.log(this.tvRequests.new);
            console.log(this.tvRequests.approved);
            console.log(this.tvRequests.available);
        });
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.requestService.getMovieGrid().subscribe(x => {
            this.movieRequests = x;
        });
        this.requestService.getTvGrid().subscribe(x => {
            this.tvRequests = x;
        });
    }


    movieRequests: IRequestGrid<IMovieRequestModel>;
    tvRequests: IRequestGrid<ITvRequestModel>;

}
```

**RequestsGrid<>.ts**

```
export interface IRequestGrid<T> {
    available: T[],
    new: T[],
    approved:T[]
}
```

The `request-card` component is just some styling and doesn't contain any code.

When I drop as you can see in the `Main View.ts` I am subscribing to the `dropModel` event and logging out to see what is going on.
Here console output for the dragging GIF above:[image]

Any idea why the item is disappearing?

**Update**
Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/U5AjZ0Gqnxq8bAznYueG?p=preview

Comment: can you create plunker? I have similar code it's working for me.

Comment: @Jonnysai I would... But not sure how to set it up with SystemJs in Plunker...

Comment: I know its very painful setup Draugla in Plunker. Longback I created basic plunker with dragula you can fork. it http://plnkr.co/edit/Mm6xq1Jhq5tisTx1y0nn?p=info

Comment: @Jonnysai Thanks for the help with that! Just updated my post with a plunker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it was the `<br/>` tags that was causing the issue!

https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula/issues/742#issuecomment-308930617